# How can I make host docker images available to k8s Deployment?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a k8s pod that is running docker. My issue is that for the docker images on my host machine to be available within the pod I either have to run the image as a pod or run a docker pull script at the beginning of my deployment.

Docker's pull API rate limits after some time and these images are not meant to be run without inputs, so I would like to know if there's another way to either expose the host's docker or get access to those images.

I am currently trying to expose the local docker socket, but that does not appear to be provide access to the Deployment from the local docker instance. I'm testing by running `docker images` inside the Deployment and on the host to see if the images match which they don't.

```
volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock:ro
      name: docker-sock
...
volumes:
    - name: docker-sock
    hostPath:
        path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

I'm also mounting with minikube like so

```
minikube start --memory='5000MB' --mount --mount-string='/:/k8s' --cpus='4'
```

Comment: You could run a registry on k3s, and explicitly push those images into the internal registry (and then access them from there rather than using the upstream reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [README](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/0c616a6b42b28a1aab8397f5a9061f8ebbd9f3d9/README.md#reusing-the-docker-daemon) describes, you can reuse the Docker daemon from Minikube with `eval $(minikube docker-env)`.

So to use an image without uploading it, you can follow these steps:

1. Set the environment variables with `eval $(minikube docker-env)`
2. Build the image with the Docker daemon of Minikube (eg `docker build -t my-image .`)
3. Set the image in the pod spec like the build tag (eg `my-image`)
4. Set the [`imagePullPolicy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images) to `Never`, otherwise Kubernetes will try to download the image.

**Important note:** You have to run `eval $(minikube docker-env)` on each terminal you want to use, since it only sets the environment variables for the current shell session.